# How to resolve error 0xc000000e

Tags: windows-7, boot

I shutdown my laptop the other night and I came back this morning and turned it on as usual, but I got this screen that said:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000e

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I am at a complete loss on what to do other than to take it into Geek Squad and having to shell out 70 bucks for them to just put an installation driver on it and reset it themselves.

Comment: Which OS? And do you have access to another computer with a DVD burner. (You can download a ISO -see http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft -  burn it and attempt to recover).

Comment: Windows 7, yes i do have a desktop.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/the-computer-has-rebooted-from-a-bugcheck-on-my/8a9f6eb2-3b32-45ef-a879-16c58de93b1c

Comment: OK ill try removing and re-inserting the HDD.

Comment: Attempt failed. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a WinRE partition? While booting, tap F8 until you get a screen that says `Repair your Computer` (or something like that) on the top of it. Then use the arrow keys to highlight the one that says `Fix startup problems...` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then go through the prompts, and reboot your computer. It may work, depending on what is wrong.

EDIT

System Restore may help, too.

- While booting, tap <kbd>F8</kbd> repeatedly
- Select `Repair your Computer` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Click `Next` (it may take some time for this to be displayed)
- Log in
- Click the `System Restore` link
- Go through the steps, and select a restore point that was created before you started noticing problems

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I tried that a few times and it takes me back to that screen telling me windows failed to start.

Comment: Have you tried System Restore?

Comment: Wouldnt know how to do that without being able to get to my home screen.

Comment: @Vonte See my edit

Comment: Tried going through f8 but it just takes me back to the windows failed to start page.

Comment: @Vonte Sounds like it must be hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help though, looks like ill have to take it in to a computer repair store.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer at [Error code: 0xc000000e in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/error-code-0xc000000e-in-windows-10/c8f62dc9-07e9-49b3-87bf-18d065db2e1b) suggests booting into a recovery environment from a Windows install medium, and trying a Startup Repair or some `bootrec` commands:

> Perform the Automatic repair:
>
> 1. When your computer starts, wait for the manufacturer logo to check the option for boot menu, it will usually be F12.
> 2. The boot menu key might differ with each manufacturer. If you are unable to find the boot menu key, you may refer the user manual.
> 3. Restart the computer, when the manufacturer's logo is displayed, keep pressing the Boot menu option key to enter the boot
>      menu and change the boot option to CD\DVD ROM.
> 4. After you boot your computer using Windows 10 DVD or System Repair Disc, a black screen appears with gray text "Press any key to
>      boot from CD or DVD". Press any key.
> 5. Select the correct time and Keyboard type.
> 6. Click Repair your computer in the lower left corner
> 7. Click on Troubleshooting, advanced option and then click Automatic repair.
>
> Method 2: You may try to rebuild the BCD booting from the disc and
>   follow these instructions:
>
> a. Insert the installation DVD or USB and boot Windows 8 from it.
>
> b. In the ‘Windows setup’ page select the ‘language to install’, 'Time
>   and currency format’ and the ‘keyboard or input method’ and click on
>   ‘next’.
>
> c. Click on Repair your computer.
>
> d. Click on Troubleshoot and then select Advanced Options.
>
> e. Click on Command prompt and type the following commands and press
>   Enter after each command:
>
> `Bootrec /fixmbr`
>
> `Bootrec /fixboot`
>
> `Bootrec /rebuildbcd`
>
> f. Restart the computer. Check if the issue persists.

https://superuser.com/a/1185649/19792 suggests the installer version does not need to be the same as the Windows version.  For Windows 7 this would be helpful nowadays, since an ISO for Windows 10 is freely available from https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10.